# Google+ option is not yet removed from Area 51 share this popup

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, share-this, google-plus

In April 2019, Google+ [shut down](https://plus.google.com/) their services to the consumers. But still the Google+ icon is displayed in the [Area 51 - Proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=newest)'s "Share This" popup.

> [image: Area 51 - Share this]

Clicking on Google Plus ([g+](https://api.addthis.com/oexchange/0.8/forward/google_plusone_share/offer?url=https%3A%2F%2Farea51.stackexchange.com%2Fproposals%2F123232%2Ftamil-language%3Freferrer%3DNjEzMmY5ZmYwY2VkODgyN2E2OWFhNDQwZmMwOWExYTkzMjM4MzRlNGQ5ODc2ZDhjYmIzYzUzMjJjMDAzZTA1OVdn1URUbQEaaRbpRnnxI1rOH2bFWuHaUpAJUKhys-qD0&title=Stack%20Exchange%20Q%26A%20site%20proposal%3A%20Tamil%20Language&username=stackexchangearea51)) icon redirecting to the warning page with the content below:

> We're sorry, but Google+ has been reported as "not working" at this time. Services can sometimes start working again quickly, so if you would like, you can try sharing to this service anyway.
>
> If you are the operator of this service and need our assistance, please contact us.

Since the g+ icon is obsolete, shall we remove it from the share this popup?
The twitter icon which is used also the old one, can it be replaced to the new icon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both the Google+ and StumbleUpon buttons in the Share dialog for Area 51 are no longer being shown.

Comment: You dared touch Area 51 code?! So brave. :-D

Comment: @ShadowTheBurningWizard Why not, now that the place is unsupervised anyway. ;-)